# Use Orca to remove assembly from installer

Tags: orca

I have a Visual Studio setup project that is built using Team Build. It has an extremely annoying habit of adding a duplicate assembly to the installer for an assembly that is already included in the installer as a project output. I am constantly having to check that the duplicate is *excluded* from the setup project but frequently the output from Team Build still includes the duplicate assembly. If this occurs, the install will fail with a message that it cannot write the duplicate to disk, because it has already just written the correct one and hasn't yet released the file handle.

I assume it is possible with Orca to remove the duplicate assembly from the installer which I'm contemplating doing in order to maintain a reasonable accord with the guy who has to run the installer. What do I need to do to remove an assembly from the installer?

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies are usually added in two tables: [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MsiAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So you can try removing the appropriate rows from these tables.

However, the best solution would be to determine why the assembly is added twice and prevent that action. Modifying the MSI after build it treating the symptoms, not the cause.

Comment: The installer has project outputs from multiple projects and those assemblies each might have dependencies on one or more of the others in the setup project. For some reason the setup project then includes the dependencies as well. I may finally have got to the bottom of the problem but I'll keep your answer as plan b.